# Can we have specific version of python created using venv - Python 3.4.3 venv using Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

Is it possible to create `Python 3.4.3` virtual environment using venv when running `Python 3.9` in my windows? I have tried with Anaconda also but the options available are only `3.8, 3.7, 3.6, 3.5 & 2.7`

If I download and install `Python 3.4.3` from python website, will it be ok? Can it run alongside `Python 3.9`?

P.S. `Python 3.4.3` is very old but one of our servers is still using it without the possibility of an update. I would like to first test my web app locally whether it works with `Python 3.4.3` before deploying.

(or)

Is it possible to create a `Python 3.9` inside `Python 3.4.3` venv? that would also solve my problem if it's possible :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install both, but i would advice to store one in user folder and the other on program files. This is to not confuse which python to run on the variable environment unless you set them to two different variable names

Comment: Thanks! I tried it now and working. Is it possible to use Python 3.4.3 by using python3.4.3 in cmd instead of referring to the path where python.exe is available?